# Javascript array of items with strange prefix

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting this array back from an API call:

```
[   
    Node { id: 123, properties: {color : 'red', shape : 'round'} },
    Node { id: 121, properties: {color : 'blue', shape : 'square'} },
    Node { id: 119, properties: {color : 'yellow', shape : 'rectangular'} }
]
```

What is this honestly? It's not an array of objects right? If it was:

```
[   
    { id: 123, properties: {color : 'red', shape : 'round'} },
    { id: 121, properties: {color : 'blue', shape : 'square'} },
    { id: 119, properties: {color : 'yellow', shape : 'rectangular'} }
]
```

And I wanted to access the "color" -property of the first item in the array i would just go:

```
myArray[0].properties.color
```

But I can't do this here because of the strange "Node" -prefix of every item in the array.

What is this thing, and how do I access any properties on it?

Comment: Where are you getting that output from exactly? Chrome Javascript console or such? It's probably simply telling you what type the object has (i.e. what class it's an instance of), you can probably still access the property exactly as shown.

Comment: Your first code block is not JSON. If you're getting it like that from an API, then it's either broken, or not a JSON API.

Comment: It's from the REST -api of neo4j (the graph database), and you are right insofar that it is describing the type (a graph node). But no - I can't access the property. @deceze

Comment: So again, where is that response from? Is that the raw REST output? Or the parsed Javascript value as seen in `console.log` or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but if this data is as simple as you present it, I suggest being lazy and replacing the `Node` from the string:

```
var str = `[   
    Node { id: 123, properties: {color : 'red', shape : 'round'} },
    Node { id: 121, properties: {color : 'blue', shape : 'square'} },
    Node { id: 119, properties: {color : 'yellow', shape : 'rectangular'} }
]`;
var withoutCrap = str.replace(/Node\s*\{/g, "{");
```

This outputs:

```
[   
    { id: 123, properties: {color : 'red', shape : 'round'} },
    { id: 121, properties: {color : 'blue', shape : 'square'} },
    { id: 119, properties: {color : 'yellow', shape : 'rectangular'} }
]
```

Note that this is still **not valid JSON**. JSON specification requires that keys are quoted `{"like": "this"}`. However you can turn it to JS object using good'ol dirty `eval`:

```
var myObject = eval("("+withoutCrap+")");
```

Those extra brackets prevent some problems I have experienced in the past.

---

The **right way** to solve this problem, however, is to fetch the **API framework** associated with this protocol (which is clearly not JSON). It will contain parser that will properly interpret the data. You should look up documentation on the site that you're connecting to.

Comment: You were right about there being a parser so I'll be able to get a clean JSON response. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.